# How to enable all three(basic, standard, full) packages for CKEditor 4.0?

Tags: ckeditor

Well I am using CKEditor 4.0, and I plan to use all three packages(basic, standard and full) for my site. The user post/topic text area will use standard CKEditor package(two lines of toolbars), the user comment/reply text area will use the basic package(one line of toolbar), while for admin creating a new article/announcement it will use the full package(4 lines of toolbars). If it sounds confusing, you can take a look at the download page for CKEditor to understand what I mean by the three packages.

http://ckeditor.com/download

So how do I achieve this, other than downloading CKEditor three times for different packages? Is it possible to selectively enable plugins for CKEditor on different pages or for different text area?

Answer (score 1):

Just as you noted, downloading every different package (basic, standard, full) of CKEditor is one quick way to achieve that, but obviously its not good for performance.

The other alternative, is to download only the 'full' package and customize the tool bars to match your needs, i.e to have only the feature in the basic, standard, or full package only in each desired context.

Do you need a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmatovu/58xfhh7b/) for this?

```js
var basic = [
  ['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink', '-', 'About']
];

var standard = [{
    name: 'document',
    items: ['NewPage', 'Preview']
  }, {
    name: 'clipboard',
    items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']
  }, {
    name: 'editing',
    items: ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt']
  }, {
    name: 'insert',
    items: ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe']
  },
  '/', {
    name: 'styles',
    items: ['Styles', 'Format']
  }, {
    name: 'basicstyles',
    items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Strike', '-', 'RemoveFormat']
  }, {
    name: 'paragraph',
    items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote']
  }, {
    name: 'links',
    items: ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']
  }, {
    name: 'tools',
    items: ['Maximize', '-', 'About']
  }
];

/* Initailise the editor with the 'basic' toolbar */
CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {
  toolbar: basic
});

/* Initailise the editor with the 'standard' toolbar *
CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {
  toolbar: standard
});
*/

/* Initailise the editor with the 'full' toolbar - default toolbar in this case is you included the full package *
CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {
  
});
*/
```

```html
<textarea name="editor"></textarea>
```

Comment: Yeah that would be nice, if you can provide an example on fiddle.